# Android WebView Refresh Page and Display Toast [HW]

Tags: java, android

This is for study and I just want to make sure my answers are 100% right. The question gives me skeleton code and I'm required to fill it in. Here is the code.

```
public class WebFragment extends WebViewFragment {

   private WebView mWebView;

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle.savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      // Fill in here
   }

   public void refreshPage(View view) {
       // Fill in here
   }

}
```

Now I am asked three questions. I have put my answers below each question.

**a. Instantiate the WebView property in the class**

**b. When the activity has started, make the WebView component load the url "http://www.google.com/"**

```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle.savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  // question a
      mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // question a
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  // question b
   }
```

**c. Assuming a button is available in the activity layout and runs refreshPage when pressed, make the function reload the WebView page and show a Toast with the message "Page has been refreshed!"**

```
   public void refreshPage(View view) {
       mWebView.reload();
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page has been refreshed!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT().show();

   }
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: it seems ok, do you have any doubt about it?

Comment: I think just with question a and c. Is what I've written for question a 'instantiating the webview property property'? And I'm not about the syntax for the Toast and whether its ok for me to do the declaration and assignment and the `show()` method at the same time.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I'm gonna answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer a seems ok, for the toast you don't need the variable, unless you don't want to do something other than showing the toast

```
mWebView.reload();
Toast.makeText(getApllicationContext(),"foo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or pass a custom time in milliseconds

```
Toast.makeText(getApllicationContext(),"foo",2000).show();
```

you can also initialize a Toast variable and than call show on it, it works, it's just a useless variable if you're not going to do anything with it but it's not wrong

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"foo",1000);
toast.show();
```

oh, I don't know if it's required, but like this refreshPage method is not callable by anybody, maybe you want to set an OnClickListener to the button (that we assume is in the layout) so that refreshPage can be called

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        refreshPage(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's right for question c. Thanks for the adaptation to the toast.

Comment: @pjmil116 you're welcome! if you have more doubts please feel free to ask ^^